# Relative Image Path in Java

Tags: java, image, relative-path

I am using:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ball.png"));

image = ii.getImage();
```

To access an image in the same folder as my .java (notepad) files (and class files after compilation).
However, I can't seem to run, only compile. Any ideas please?

I can get this to work in Eclipse but not in straight Java files written in Notepad.

Sorry, for not getting back to this but I have been trying something else.

I have tried: ImageIcon("C:/path/to/your/appication/ball.png");

And it doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to find a way to reference images from a straight Java Notepad file, not using any IDE. When I have the classes in Eclipse, they work, after taking the Java files and copying them elsewhere, I remove the package references, I can compile but after I try to run all I get are the following error messages:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at Ball.loadImage(Ball.java:26)
    at Ball.initBall(Ball.java:18)
    at Ball.<init>(Ball.java:10)
    at Board.gameInit(Board.java:50)
    at Board.initBoard(Board.java:43)
    at Board.<init>(Board.java:34)
    at Breakout.initUI(Breakout.java:19)
    at Breakout.<init>(Breakout.java:14)
    at Breakout.lambda$main$0(Breakout.java:32)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: What about putting the image in the resource folder?

Comment: That works if I am using eclipse but what do I do if I am just using straight Java files with no IDE?

Comment: Add the files to tge classpath when running.

Comment: Note that you are attempting to use `Class.getResource(...)` to load a resource that has been packaged into the jar file (eclipse does this automatically for you), however, when you do this manually (notepad) you need to make sure that the file is packaged into your jar, or you need to load it using a file path for files that are not packaged into your jar, for example `new ImageIcon("C:/path/to/your/appication/ball.png");`

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null` this tells you that `location` is `null`. but it's not shown in your code - maybe you show us the relevant part of your code?